# SP routine ClientContext fails except in Edit Mode

Tags: jquery, sharepoint, editor, spservices

I have an issue with Javascript errors (Object Expected) in normal mode while it works in Edit mode. Its failing on the last line shown below.

```
 $(document).ready(function() { updateListItem(); });

      function updateListItem() {

        var siteUrl = ‘/sites2/sppwgrqy/DashboardTest/’; alert(‘now to get siteUrl’ + siteUrl );

        var clientContext = new SP.ClientContext(siteUrl ); //fails hereNo hidden components.

   }
```

works fine in Edit mode. I upgraded to jquery 1.8.3 and then 1.9.0 with no change.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Ok so honestly, I never found out why this approach only works in Edit mode.
so I used a SPServices option:

```
<script type="text/javascript">
//Wrapping your script in $(document).ready(function()means 
//that the calls will be made once the page is fully loaded,
// i.e., the page is "ready". 

$(document).ready(function() {
   updateReleaseSelected();
});

function updateReleaseSelected()
{    
   var relID = document.getElementById('ReleaseID').value;
   //  alert('RelID:' +  relID );
   updateItems(relID );
};

function updateItems(relID)
{  
  $().SPServices(
  {
      operation: 'UpdateListItems',
      webURL: '/sites2/sppwgrqy/DashboardTest/',
      listName: 'ReleaseSelected',
      updates: '<Batch OnError="Continue" PreCalc="True">' + 
         '<Method ID="1" Cmd="Update">' +
         '<Field Name="ReleaseValue">' + relID + '</Field>' +
         '<Field Name="ID">2</Field>' +
         '</Method>' +
         '</Batch>',
      completefunc: function(xData, Status)
      {
          //alert('successfully updated');      
      }
  });
}
</script>
```